# Conjunction Annotator Simple Explaination for Dewey Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree, rule-engine, boolean-expression

I am trying to implement the Dewey Algorithm for boolean expression evaluation optimization.

Reference for Dewey Algorithm - http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/sigmod10-index.pdf

Two things that I am looking for help

- I am not able to comprehend the "Conjunction Annotator" concept. I would appreciate if someone can explain me how to do it.
- Also if there is an existing implementation of Dewey algorithm in any programming language I would be willing to use instead of re-writing it. (my language  of preference is java but any programming language will do since I can understand it.)